# Free document management system with file system integration

Tags: gratis, document-management

I'm looking for a DMS, preferably lightweight, with the following features:

Essential:

- Items stored in a logical hierarchical structure in DMS DB, albeit with tagging for easy searching
- Stores documents on file system in a structure that reflects the above
- Monitoring of folders, automatically adding new files to the DMS with
  whatever meta data can be gleamed from the file/location
- Free (open source useful but not essential)
- Customisable email updates when new docs matching names/locations/other meta data matches

Desirable:

- SQL Server backend - already have on server
- Windows client detects when you are dropping file on server and prompts for metadata
- AD authentication
- Front-end security matches NTFS permissions

Useful:

- .NET based or with an .NET API
- OCR capability
- Outlook/Office plugins

I think that Alfresco Community + CMISSync would cover many of my needs, but it looks horrendously complicated and I would only use a fraction of the functionality, and the whole platform is new and would not be useful to me elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Nextcloud](https://nextcloud.com).

It has most of the features you are looking for and many plugins/apps in an Nextcloud App Store.

There is a windows integrations available (WebDAV) as well as email notifications for updated documents.

Even AD is available in the communit version.

Comment: Does it match the `email updates when new docs matching names/locations/other meta data matches` requirement? If yes, please describe how to set up a metadata match alert, thanks!